# Javascript Debugging Issue: "Uncaught ReferenceError: canvas is not defined"

Tags: javascript, canvas

My chrome Browser console gives the error defined above when it runs my code.
This is only a  portion of my code, and I am following the framework of the KeyBoard Navigation-Control example posted on w3.schools.com: (https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_controllers_keys).

I previously had mainCanvas as a function,and the canvas property had an "=" for its definition, instead of ":". This worked fine at first, but then discrepancy with the tutorial began to confuse me. Once I switched my function to an Object -- as per the tutorial -- , I started having this issue. I'm new to Javascript, and so I'd really appreciate your help!

```
function parent(){
    mainCanvas.load();
}

  var mainCanvas = {

        canvas : document.getElementById("myCanvas"),

        load: function(){
            //ctx1.beginPath();
            ctx1 = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx1.canvas.width = (window.innerWidth)/2;
            ctx1.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            ctx1.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, ctx1.canvas.width, ctx1.canvas.width);
            //ctx1.fillStyle = "blue";
            //if (diffColor == true)
                //ctx1.fillStyle = "yellow";
            //ctx1.fillRect(30, 30, 100, 150);

            document.body.insertBefore(canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            interval = setInterval(moveTracker, 20);

            window.addEventListener ("keydown", function(e){
                console.log(e.keyCode);
                mainCanvas.key = e.keyCode; //execute movement when key pressed
                if (e.keyCode == 38)
                    diffColor = true;
                else
                    diffColor = false;
            });
            window.addEventListener ("keyup", function(e){
                    mainCanvas.key = false; //stop movement once key is released
                    })
        },

        clear: function(){
            ctx1.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
        //ctx1.fill();
    }
```

Comment: `canvas` in your code is not a variable, it's a property of `mainCanvas` object. `this.canvas` should do the trick. Notice, that you're creating a global variable `ctx1` in the method, always declare your variables.

Comment: `canvas` is a property of the `mainCanvas` object. `canvas.getContext("2d")` is attempting to find `canvas` on the global scope (window object).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Randy! Based on your answer, I've tried to declare canvas as a variable instead of a property, but this hasn't been suuccesful -- I'm supposing since mainCanvas is an object. Do you have a suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Teemu. I get a "syntax error - unexpected token   .   " feedback when I use this.canvas instead...

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. `let ctx1 = this.canvas.getContext("2d");` should it be.